# From where i can define the incomming email address for a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, incoming-email

i am using SharePoint 2013 , and i added a new announcement list, then i configured the list to accept emails. but i can not understand from where i can define the announcement list email address ? and should this email be created inside our exchange server first ?
Second question. how do SharePoint map the email content to the announcement item content.

will for example the email subject be the announcement subject ? and the email body mapped to the announcement item body ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the announcements list for which you want to enable and configure incoming e-mail support.

Click **Settings,** and then click **List Settings**.
Under **Communications**, click **Incoming e-mail settings**.

In the **E-Mail** section, choose **Yes** to enable this list to receive e-mail, and then type the **alias** that you want to use to send e-mail to this list.

P.S.  The Incoming e-mail settings link is not available if incoming e-mail support is not enabled in Central Administration.

**Behind the scenes:**

As soon as Alias is created on the SharePoint side, a contact will be [auto created](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jvasil/archive/2012/11/05/in-coming-email-names-for-email-enabled-lists-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) in Active directory and Exchange server

For the announcement list, SharePoint will capture subject, body, and original message from your email message.